# Rate of change $\frac{dV}{dt}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have the following task: "Poiscuille's Law: $V=\frac{P}{4Lv} (R^2 - r^2)$. Assume that $r$ is a constant as well as $P,L,v$. Find the rate of change $\frac{dV}{dt}$ in terms of $R$ and $\frac{dR}{dt}$ when $L=1$mm, $p=100$, $v=0.05$."

I cannot understand how can how can diff that, what is the $t$ here? I can write $V = 500 (R^2 - r^2)$. But what after? And what is "find the rate of change in terms of...? Something like: $\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dV}{dR}\frac{dR}{dt}$? I am right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a function
$$V(R)=\frac{p}{4Lv}(R^2-r^2)$$
But $R$ is a function of the time, so you have that
$$V(t)=V(R(t))=\frac{p}{4Lv}(R^2(t)-r^2)$$
So you are right, you should just use the chain rule.

Comment: Ou, $R$ is function of the time?  This was not written in the task...

Comment: @Arsenii For me (and I think for the author of the question as well), the appearance of $\frac{\mathrm{d}R}{\mathrm{d}t}$ implies that $R$ is a function of $t$.

Comment: @Arsenii Or you can "feel" it from the fact that everything except the $R$ is a constant, so $R$ must be time-dependent to make some sense. But of course, it is not a mathematically correct way to state a problem, but it's common in physics.

Comment: Okey, thx) 
It was not obvious to me)